# Changing category names in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, rename, categories

I was wondering if there was any way to change the category names in a pandas dataframe, I tried to use the `labels.rename_categories({'zero': '0', 'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3', 'four': '4', 'five': '5', 'six': '6', 'seven': '7', 'eight': '8', 'nine': '9'})` but that didn't work unfortunately.

here is what the pandas dataframe currently looks like

```
                              File  Label
20936  eight/b63fea9e_nohash_1.wav  eight
21016  eight/f44f440f_nohash_2.wav  eight
7423   three/d8ed3745_nohash_0.wav  three
1103    zero/ad63d93c_nohash_4.wav   zero
13399   five/5b09db89_nohash_0.wav   five
...                            ...    ...
13142   five/1a892463_nohash_0.wav   five
21176  eight/810c99be_nohash_0.wav  eight
16908  seven/6d818f6c_nohash_0.wav  seven
15308    six/2bfe70ef_nohash_1.wav    six
646     zero/24632875_nohash_0.wav   zero

[23666 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### TL;DR

1. Use [`Series.cat.rename_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.rename_categories.html) for **categorical** variables.
2. Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) for **non-categorical** variables.
3. Use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) if **regex** is needed.

   [image]

---

#### 1. [`Series.cat.rename_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.rename_categories.html)

This option is fastest but requires the [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) dtype. If you're analyzing categorical variables, this is highly recommended for its [speed/memory/semantic benefits](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html).

First convert to [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) (if not already):

```py
df['Label'] = df['Label'].astype('category')
```

Then rename via [`Series.cat.rename_categories`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.rename_categories.html):

```
df['Label'] = df['Label'].cat.rename_categories({'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5, 'six': 6, 'seven': 7, 'eight': 8, 'nine': 9})

#                               File Label
# 20936  eight/b63fea9e_nohash_1.wav     8
# 21016  eight/f44f440f_nohash_2.wav     8
# 7423   three/d8ed3745_nohash_0.wav     3
# ...                            ...   ...
# 646     zero/24632875_nohash_0.wav     0
```

---

#### 2. [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

If you can't (or don't want to) use the [`Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) dtype, [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) is the next fastest:

```py
df['Label'] = df['Label'].map({'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5, 'six': 6, 'seven': 7, 'eight': 8, 'nine': 9})

#                               File Label
# 20936  eight/b63fea9e_nohash_1.wav     8
# 21016  eight/f44f440f_nohash_2.wav     8
# 7423   three/d8ed3745_nohash_0.wav     3
# ...                            ...   ...
# 646     zero/24632875_nohash_0.wav     0
```

---

#### 3. [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)

This option is slow but offers regex/filling capabilities via the `regex` and `method` params.

As a contrived example, say we want less granular labels:

```py
mapping = {
    r'zero|one': '0,1',
    r'two|three': '2,3',
    r'four|five': '4,5',
    r'six|seven': '6,7',
    r'eight|nine': '8,9',
}
```

Then we can use [`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with `regex=True`:

```py
df['Label'] = df['Label'].replace(mapping, regex=True)

#                               File Label
# 20936  eight/b63fea9e_nohash_1.wav   8,9
# 7423   three/d8ed3745_nohash_0.wav   2,3
# 1103    zero/ad63d93c_nohash_4.wav   0,1
# ...                            ...   ...
# 646     zero/24632875_nohash_0.wav   0,1
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that `rename_categories` does not work if there are duplicate mappings.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
label_dict = {'zero': 0,
        'one' : 1,
        'two': 2,
        'three' : 3,
        'four': 4,
        'five': 5,
        'six' : 6,
        'seven' : 7,
        'eight' : 8,
        'nine' : 9,
        }
df['Label'] = df['Label'].apply( lambda x : label_dict[x])
```

Answer (score 2):

By changeing the category names, you are meaning to replace the values by a dictionary. Am I correct?

Try it like that:

```py
df = df["label"].replace({
    'zero': '0', 
    'one': '1', 
    'two': '2', 
    'three': '3', 
    'four': '4', 
    'five': '5', 
    'six': '6', 
    'seven': '7', 
    'eight': '8', 
    'nine': '9'
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you, Sorted! I used `df['Labels'] = df['Labels'].replace({
    'zero': '0', 
    'one': '1', 
    'two': '2', 
    'three': '3', 
    'four': '4', 
    'five': '5', 
    'six': '6', 
    'seven': '7', 
    'eight': '8', 
    'nine': '9'
  }
). I used the df['Labels'] = to avoid overwriting the rest of the dataframe with the renamed categories.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.replace()` with your dictionary as the `to_replace` arg.

Here's the doc

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html